# What is Shaktipata?

Tags: philosophy, practice, tantra

Can anyone explain about it with good examples?

What are the different types of ***Shaktipata***?

Answer (score 7):

**Shaktipata** is the most essential part of the the **Tantrik Deeksha Samskara.** It literally means the transfer of energy from Guru to the disciple.

In KulArnava Tantram Lord Shiva clearly says, that Deeksha where Shaktipata is absent fails to bear any fruits.

> ShaktipAtAnusArena Shishyohanugrahamaharti |
>    Yatra Shaktirna Patati Tatra Siddhirna JAyate ||
>
> ### Meaning
>
> According to Shaktipata a disciple receives Guru's anugraha. **There is
>   no siddhi (accomplishment) where there is no Shaktipata.**
>
> **KulArnava Tantram, Chapter 14, Verse 38.**

And, this transfer of energy can be achieved by mainly three methods as given below:

> ### SparsakhyA Deeksha
>
> This is also known as **Sparsha Deeksha** or simply **Sparshani**. ( Sparsha
>   means touch). In this , the Guru meditates on his own Guru as Parama
>   Shiva in his own hand. Then he performs Mula Mantra Shadanga Nyasa,
>   Matrika Nyasas etc and then places his right hand on the shishya's
>   head. After that Mantra upadesam is done. This is called Sparsha
>   Deeksha and its extremely fruitful (siddhiprada).
>
> ### Drik Sanga Deeksha
>
> This is also known as **Drik Deeksha** or simply **Chaksushi**. (Drik relates
>   to vision ). Here the Guru contemplates on Paramatma Shiva with closed
>   eyes and after having vision of Him he opens eyes and views the
>   disciple with  eyes filled with joy. Then with a happy mind
>   (prasanna chitta) he initiates the disciple into the mantra. This
>   Deeksha is also known as **Phaladayini Deeksha** and is highly fruitful.
>
> ### MAnasAkyA Deeksha
>
> This is also known as **Manasa Deeksha** or **Mano Deeksha** or **Vedamayi
>   Deeksha**. ( Manas is mind). Here the Guru meditates on the
>   Kulakundalini Shakti which is situated within the four petaled lotus in the
>   disciple's Muladhara Chakra. And  meditating thus, he moves the Shakti upwards
>   by piercing the Shatchakras and unites it with Shiva who is in the Sahsrara
>   Chakra. By doing so, by the Guru's order, the disciple gets rid of
>   three Pashas namely Sahaja, Agantuka and Sangsagika. The disciple is
>   then filled with Shivatva and becomes like no other than the supreme
>   Shiva. This Deeksha is considered as the one to give the quickest
>   results among all and also as the most fruitful among all Shaktipata Deekshas.

Lord Shiva mentions about these 3 kinds of highly beneficial Deekshas in the following verse:

> SparshakhyA Devi DriksangyA MAnasAkhyA Maheswari |
>   KriyAyAsAdirahitA Devi DeekshA TridhA SmritA ||
>
> Devi, Hey Maheswari, Sparsha, Drik and Manas, Deekshas are of these
>   three kinds. In these three Deekshas elaborate rituals (Ayasha and
>   Kriya) are not needed.
>
> **Kularnava Tantram, Chpater 14, Verse 34.**

As an additional note, elaborate rituals are needed for Deekshas called the **Kriyavati Deeksha** which are the ones that are usually practiced. Descriptions related to them are found in the same chapter of the aforementioned Tantra Text.

Comment: Are there any examples like someone in ancient or in modern times got initiation by Shakti pata , like someone whome we all know.

Comment: In ancient times Shaktipata was always practiced. In modern times however its not all always practiced. There must be many  examples like  Sri Ramakrishna gave Shaktipata to his disciples.

Comment: Ok :)..........

Comment: @SwiftPushkar plenty in maharastra. Kaka maharaj dhekane, Gulvani maharaj, swami nityananda and muktananda of ganeshpuri etc.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi - Yes , you are correct ,as I often heard about this through discussions and from articles written in various spiritual magzines :-)

Comment: this phenomenon should hold true in all yugas and all times.