# What is shakti patam?

Tags: practice

I heard that shakti patam is related to conscious flow of energy inside human body, but do not know in detail.

What is meant by **shakti patam** exactly and which scripture deals with it in detail?

Comment: Saktipat is considered an act of grace (anugraha) on the part of the guru or the divine. It cannot be imposed by force, nor can a receiver make it happen. In this Wikipedia article, it was stated that Kashmir Shaivism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashmir_Shaivism) elaborates different levels of Shakti pat@hanugm

Comment: See my answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18210/what-is-shaktipata .. Yours is a duplicate.

Comment: Do you agree that this question is a duplicate of the one I linked?

Comment: @Rickross Yeah, but has a doubt, can it occur even without guru? I mean can goddesses directly give shakti patham?

Comment: Ok I'm then casting my vote, Not sure, may be, but it is part of the process of initiation (Diksha). So, Guru showers the grace. BTW Guru is also divine for the disciple. One who thinks his/her Guru to be a mere mortal does not achieve anything good from the Diksha. @hanugm