# Full kundalini awakening by a Guru?

Tags: kundalini

Can a Guru do the job of raising kundalini for the upAsakA?I know many won't do it,but is it possible?

Comment: (Perhaps this is a nitpick, but I wouldn't call it the guru's "job" to do this.)

Comment: @Brahadeesh You may want to read this: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54912392#54912392

Comment: possible, but can lead to disastrous consequences if the person is not ready to handle. It is why many that can do not.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Interesting, I did not know that! However, I'm still not sure whether that is an argument in favour of using the word "job" to describe that particular action.

Comment: @Brahadeesh Now I understood your concern. Yes definitely it's not his "job".

Comment: It seems that apparently is possible , but not really suggested.  Many people said to have attained a Kundalini awakening through a "guru". Strange enough, they continue to talk about it as a mechanical thing. Real Kundalini is raised by itself and the power of Dharma. It does not need any Guru to be awakened.

Answer (score 5):

The moment the disciple receives Mantra Upadesham, his (or her) Kundali is awakened from the sleep it was in prior to the initiation.

This is in fact the very purpose of Mantra Diksha to awaken the Kundali and to purify it.

> Shri ChadikovAcha ----
>
> mantra-dhArana-mAtrena tatkshanAt tanmayo bhavet |
>  jivAtmA
> kundali-madhye pradipakalika yathA ||
>
> Shri ChandikA said---- The moment the disciple receives the Mantra,
> the Kundalini (the Jiva within the Kundalini) is awakened like a
> lamp's wick.
>
> **Shri MAtrikA Bheda Tantra; Patala 14; Verse 1.**

As long as the Upashaka's Kundali is still in slumber there is no scope of any kind of spiritual upliftment or perfection (neither Siddhi nor Sadgati).

And, since Mantra Diksha serves the purpose of arousing the Kundalini Shakti from sleep, it is considered as the first step towards any kind of spiritual progress which ultimately ends with final liberation.

So, the short answer is, the SathGuru awakens the disciple's Kundalini at the moment of initiation itself.

It is also possible for a SathGuru to completely awaken the Kundalini Shakti of the disciple at the moment of Diksha and can even move it up till the highest Chakra i.e. the Sahsrara Chakra.

This is possible through Shaktipat (or the transfer of energy that happens due to the Guru's grace).

On the topic of Shaktipat there is [an answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18212/4732) already.

In it you will see about three kind of initiations being talked about --- Sparsha, Drik and Manas.

> SparshakhyA Devi DriksangyA MAnasAkhyA Maheswari |
> KriyAyAsAdirahitA Devi DeekshA TridhA SmritA ||
>
> O Devi, O Maheswari, Sparsha, Drik and Manas --- Dikshas are of these
> three kinds. In these three Dikshas elaborate rituals (Ayasha and
> Kriya) are not needed.
>
> **Kularnava Tantram, Chpater 14, Verse 34.**

Among these three, during the Manasa Diksha, the Guru helps pierce the disciple's Shat Chakras and move his Kundalini upwards.

> This is also known as Manasa Deeksha or Mano Deeksha or the Vedamayi
> Deeksha. (Manas is mind). Here the Guru meditates on the
> Kulakundalini Shakti which is situated within the four petaled lotus
> in the disciple's Muladhara Chakra. And meditating thus, he moves the
> Shakti upwards by piercing the Shatchakras and unites it with Shiva,
> who is in the Sahsrara Chakra. By doing so, by the Guru's order, the
> disciple gets rid of the three Pashas namely Sahaja, Agantuka and
> Sangsagika. The disciple is then filled with Shivatva and becomes like
> no other than the supreme Shiva. This Deeksha is considered as the one
> to give the quickest results among all and also as the most fruitful
> among all Shaktipat Deekshas.

So, it is very much possible for SathGurus.

Comment: Really good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,this is not mentioned in any yoga upnishads,or any prominent texts of kundalini yoga , However most of mass believe  that this is actually possible,and some traditional stories also talk about that ,this method of raising kundalini by mercy of qualified guru is often called as ShaktipAth

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism StackExchange! Answer posted here must be backed up authentic sources. Please visit [help section](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more.

Comment: How a shishya will. Come to know that, his kundalini has awakened. What are those symptoms in his/her body that signals, his kundalini awakening has happened?.. is it kind of a vibration happening in his/her body? Or he/she is able to listen Goddess's ghungroo (Chilanka) sound? Or he/she understands what birds talking to each other? When he enters a room, he feels, someone else is also in that room? Narayan dutt shrimali ji has mentioned,  in a youtube video,  something abt ghungroo /goddesss presence in the room,  when he talks abt Ugra Tara Upasana/Sadhana..  is that true?